# How do I "cast" an inherited delegate?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have these Delegates and want to use them in an interface. How do I do the Properties for the inherited Delegates Correctly?

```
 public delegate List<IValueAble>? RunDelegate(params IParameter[]? args);
public delegate List<IValueAble<T>>? RunDelegate<T>(params IParameter[]? args);
public delegate List<IValueAble<T>>? RunDelegate<T, K>(params IParameter<K>[]? args);
public interface IRunnAble
{
    public RunDelegate? RunDel { get; set; }
}

public interface IRunnAble<T> : IRunnAble
{
    new public RunDelegate<T>? RunDel { get; set; }
}

public interface IRunnAble<T,K> : IRunnAble<T>
{
    new public RunDelegate<T,K>? RunDel { get; set; }
}
```

This is the part I dont know how to implement:

```
 public RunDelegate<T,K>? RunDel { get; set; }
 RunDelegate<T>? IRunnAble<T>.RunDel { get => RunDel<T,object> //??; set => //?? What I need to implement
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work:

```
 public RunDelegate<T>? RunDel { get; set; }
    RunDelegate? IRunnAble.RunDel { 
        get => (IParameter[]? args) => { return RunDel?.Invoke(args).Cast<IValueAble>().ToList(); }; 
        set => RunDel = (IParameter[]? args) => value?.Invoke(args).Cast<IValueAble<T>>().ToList();
    }
```